# rails remove element in real time

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, actioncable

Got a link that removes a message from the current_users screen:

```
= link_to '[x]', msg, method: :delete, remote: true, class: "del-link"
```

It triggers this coffeescript-funktion:

```
delete_message = () ->
$('.del-link').on 'ajax:success', (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  $(this).closest('.message').remove()
  return
```

and this rails-method:

```
def destroy
  @msg = Msg.find(params[:id])
  @msg.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to chat_path }
    format.json { head :no_content }
    format.js   { render :layout => false }
  end
end
```

But how would it be done, that the message is removed on every users screen, e.g. using ActionCable?

The coffeescript for the chat:

```
App.proom = App.cable.subscriptions.create "ProomChannel",
  connected: ->
    # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

  disconnected: ->
    # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

  received: (data) ->
    unless data.msg.blank?
        $('#messages-table').append data.msg
        scroll_bottom()


 $(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
   submit_msg()
   scroll_bottom()
   delete_message()
```

the channel.rb

```
class ProomChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "proom_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
  end
end
```

## Approach

So I added this to the destroy-action of the controller

```
if msg.destroy
  ActionCable.server.broadcast 'proom_channel', msg: @msg
end
```

Also I added an ID to every message-div-element containing the id of the message-record to find and remove it from the DOM with the following line

```
$("msg_#{msg.id}").remove()
```

But now I don't know where to put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not able to give you right now the complete answer, but I will update my answer later if you do not find a solution:

Like when you create a message with action cable, after saving the message in the DB, you trigger an `ActionCable.server.broadcast 'messages'` that will execute some JS included for example in the User Browser asset pipeline file `app/assets/javascripts/channels/messages.js`

This is my message controller, once I save the message, I start the `Server.broadcast` process. It will trigger the process in my `messages_channel.rb` that will update all clients that are subscribed to that channel.

```
  def create
    message = Message.new(message_params)
    message.user = current_user ￼
    chatroom = message.chatroom
    if message.save
        ActionCable.server.broadcast 'messages',
        message: message.content,
        user: message.user.name,
        chatroom_id: message.chatroom_id,
        lastuser: chatroom.messages.last(2)[0].user.name
      head :ok
    end
  end
```

Image and text is from the following article of [Sophie DeBenedetto](https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable)

> We add our new subscription to our consumer with
>   App.cable.subscriptions.create. We give this function an argument of
>   the name of the channel to which we want to subscribe,
>   MessagesChannel.
>
> When this subscriptions.create function is invoked, it will invoke the
>   MessagesChannel#subscribed method, which is in fact a callback method.
>
> MessagesChannel#subscribed streams from our messages broadcast,
>   sending along any new messages as JSON to the client-side subscription
>   function.
>
> Then, the received function is invoked, with an argument of this new
>   message JSON. The received function in turn calls a helper function
>   that we have defined, renderMessage, which simply appends new messages
>   to the DOM, using the $("#messages") jQuery selector, which can be
>   found on the chatroom show page.

[image: The Message Channel]

The channel will call the `messages.js` function `received`, that will append the div to the DOM, you will need to call an alternative action in `messages.js`.

```
App.messages = App.cable.subscriptions.create('MessagesChannel', {      
  received: function(data) {
      // code executed - the parameters will be in data.chatroom_id and 
      // data.user, data.message etc...
  }
});
```

So you will need to call the channel from your action `messages#destroy`, have in `messages.js` a specific function to remove the div from the DOM.
I don't know if you will need to create a specific server side channel or you can just edit your present `messages_channel.rb` to include a specific function.. You need to read the guides and figure this out.. I may try this in the future, but right now I can't

Or an easy alternative, just write some js in `messages.js` to solve this and have the div removed when required.. for example the `messages#destroy` action can pass a parameter and if that parameters is present, you will remove the message, instead of adding it

https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable#channel-example-1-user-appearances

Comment: It seems there has been some editing mishap, as the opening paragraphs are repeated after the first code block.

Comment: @vijoc I don't know what you mean

Comment: I think you pasted your first two paragraphs inside you first codeblock by mistake

Comment: Now its beneath it, but its still a repetition

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio pls have a look at my updated question

Comment: Hello @Max tomorrow morning I will try to help you find a solution. Thanks a lot! Fabrizio

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio I just solved it by myself, but thanks for your effort

Comment: @Max Great! I think that you need to put it in the `received` function of your `messages.js` file in `app/assets/javascripts/channels/messages.js` your js code `$("msg_#{msg.id}").remove()`, but as you use the `messages_channel.rb` both to post and delete messages through `messages.js`, you have to make sure that you correctly trigger the 2 functions. Anyway the concept of `messages.js received:` function is that as this is a `AJAX` call between server making a `request` to the client and the client responding with a `response`, the concept of `received:` inside `messages.js`

Comment: is for the successful establishing of connection between server and client. To understand more about `AJAX` this are some useful links 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0crKwijP0Q
and this is practical AJAX done with Jquery 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEYx8dQr_cQ
This is essential to understand Action Cable, but also the documentation above is essential